# DDD: How should adding and removing related entities be modelled?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Say we have two aggregate roots in a domain model: Group and User.

Now, Users can be added to or removed from groups. Using the repository pattern, I only modelled the following two interfaces so far:

```
interface IGroupRepository
{
    Group FindById(int groupId);
}
interface IUserRepository
{
    User FindById(int userId);
    IQueryable<User> GetGroupMembers(int groupId);
    void AddUserToGroup(User user, Group group);
    void RemoveUserFromGroup(User user, Group group);
}
```

Somehow, the doesn't feel right. I want to achieve a clean domain model and not end up with a mere data-access layer. What would be a better way to model the above?

**EDIT:** The root question here seems to be, is it OK with DDD's guidelines to treat User as a 'sub-object' while it at the same time is an aggregate root as well? As I understood DDD, it states that aggregate roots must only be retrieved and stored from one place (the repository) so that's why I get a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a ORM such as NHibernate to it's full potential you can have methods like this:

```
class Group
{
    List<User> members;

    void Join(User user)
    {
        members.Add(user);
    }

    void Leave(User user)
    {
        members.Remove(user);
    }
}
```

A decent ORM will track the changes to the members list and persist those to the database.

This would enable your interfaces to be simplified to:

```
interface IGroupRepository
{
    Group FindById(int groupId);
}

interface IUserRepository
{
    User FindById(int userId);
}
```

[This](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/13/nhibernate-mapping-lt-set-gt.aspx) should give you some guidance on doing this with NHibernate.

Comment: NHibernate info can now be found at http://nhforge.org/ - the older site has been down for a while now

Comment: Isn't this approach treating User as not being an aggregate root? I am confused

btw, I don't care about persistance just yet - just looking for the general design pattern

Comment: Sort of. If you only consider this situation then it probably isn't an aggregate root. However, I'm assuming you'd use the User for much more. The only reason to have a repository is as a way of persisting (mostly). So imagine how you'd model it without the repository first.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would consider creating a collection of Groups on the User or vice versa. That way you do not need a specialized method on the repository. Most ORM frameworks support this kind of mapping

```
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The core question seems to be if it breaks the consistency of the domain model to treat User as a 'sub-object' when it is in fact an aggregate root. Gonna edit the question a bit

Comment: After thinking more about it, it DOES seem natural to have a Users collection on a Group. It should maybe just be perceived as a list of references to the aggregate root instances